# Creating a table in D3 with Json Object

Tags: d3.js

My data is a Json Array of Below Json Object -

```
var data = [{id: 0, reflexive: false}]
```

I want to show a table of these properties with key as a label in first td and value in an input box in second td.
So for above data I want two rows. First row with first td value should be id and second td value should be 0. Similarly in second row, first td value should be reflexive and second td value should be false.

Below is the code which I have implemented now -

```
var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
        .attr("style", "margin-left: 250px; border: 2px"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(column) { return column; });
        alert(data);

// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data[0].keys().length())
    .enter()
    .append("tr");

    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
.append("input")
.attr('disabled', null)
.attr("name", "byName")
.attr("type", "text")
.attr("value",function(d) { return d.value; })

return table;
```

But its giving output as a single row with key as headers and values in td. Any suggestion would help.

Comment: what is columns? post your entire code.

Comment: My columns are static text value as  - var columns=["Property Name", "Property Value"];

Comment: why do you have data like this var ary = [{id: 0, reflexive: false}];
shouldn't it be 
_var ary = {id: 0, reflexive: false, moreKey:someValue};_ I mean it shold nt be a json array but just a json object with some key value.

Answer (score 1):

I have considered the data to be like this instead of the array in your example above

```
var ob = {id: 0, reflexive: false};
```

You need to make this an array of key value like this:

```
data = Object.keys(ob).map(function(k) { return {key:k, value:ob[k]} })
```

Now make a table and tr and tds depending on the data like below:

```js
var ob = {id: 0, reflexive: false};

data = Object.keys(ob).map(function(k) { return {key:k, value:ob[k]} })


var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
        .attr("style", "margin-left: 50px; border: 2px"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(["Property Name", "Property Value"])
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(d) { console.log(d);return d; });


// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");
    ///add the key in first td
    rows.append("td")
 .text(function(d) { ;return d.key; });
 ///add the value in second td
    rows
    .append("td")
 .append("input")
 .attr('readonly', true)
 .attr("name", "byName")
 .attr("type", "text")
 .attr("value",function(d) { return d.value; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```